# fragments, some tips

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm new on android development and I need some tips from you.
I'm creating an app and I'm using fragments following the google docs for android.

Now, the app is working fine for now but I have some questions about "good coding style".

So, I decided to split activity2 into 2 fragments for now and I've added a fragment programmatically (no xml tag declared) and by using an interface and a callback method I'm able to call another fragment and pass an object.

There is the code for help you to understand what i mean:
Activity2:

LEGEND: SegnalazioneFotoMappa des==fragment2
        UserLog==fragment1

```
public class ActivitySegnalazione extends AppCompatActivity implements ObjectSender{
    private Segnalazione segnalazione= null;
    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transiction=null;
    private UserLog user=null;
    private DescrizioneFotoMappa des=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segnalazione);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        segnalazione=new Segnalazione();
        user= new UserLog();
        user.setSegnalazione(segnalazione);
        manager=getFragmentManager();
        transiction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transiction.add(R.id.acsegn, user, "userfrag" );
        transiction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void sender(Segnalazione segnalazione1) {
        des= new DescrizioneFotoMappa(); //fragment2
        des.setSegnalazione(segnalazione1);
        FragmentTransaction transiction2= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transiction2.replace(R.id.acsegn, des).addToBackStack("frag1").commit();

    }
}
```

and that's the onResume method of fragment1
LEGEND: obj== interface

```
@Override
     public void onResume()
     {
         super.onResume();
         text= (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
         text2=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         text3=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
         bottone1= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
         obj=(ObjectSender) getActivity(); //Reference to activity

         bottone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 segnalazione.setNome(text2.getText().toString());
                 segnalazione.setCognome(text3.getText().toString());
                 obj.sender(segnalazione);
             }
         });
     }
```

I know that the code is a mess, but is the "fragments logic" that I'm using correct? The code is working as I said.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I highly recommend you write your code in English. It's really hard for someone else to understand your code if all variables, functions and classes have names which are gibberish to them.

Comment: Also adding and not replacing a fragment in onStart looks strange to me, I usually do such transactions in onCreate. If you call add multiple times the app will crash saying that the fragment was already added. So to test this, try to open this activity, press Home button and then open the app again. This should trigger onStart for the second time. I'm not 100% sure that it will crash but please double check. You might have a bug there.

Comment: Yep sorry for the language, I'm working with some italians guys and I just copied and pasted the code. Anyway, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you are keeping a reference to the Activity in fragment1 in the `obj` instance variable which is set in `onResume()`.

In your example, you should set the (properly cast and Exception-checked) Activity reference in the Fragment's `onAttach()` method and set it to **null** in the `onDetach()` method. This ensures loose coupling of the Fragment and the Activity holding it.

In your example, in fragment1:

```
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof ObjectSender) {
        obj = (ObjectSender) context; //Reference to activity
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement ObjectSender");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    obj = null;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   text= (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   text2=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
   text3=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
   bottone1= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);

   bottone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           segnalazione.setNome(text2.getText().toString());
           segnalazione.setCognome(text3.getText().toString());
           obj.sender(segnalazione);
       }
   });
}
```

Other than that, your Fragment logic looks fine.